# Finding the maximum of a complex valued function on a set

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, continuity

Let $R$ be the right half plane {$z ∈ \mathbb C : Re (z) > 0$}, and let $λ > 0$.

(a) Show that the function $e^{−λ/z}$ is holomorphic on $R$ and continuous on $\bar{R}$\ {$0$}.

(b) Does the limit lim$_{z→0}$ $e^{−λ/z}$ exist? What about $z$lim$_{z→0}$ $e^{−λ/z}$?

(c) Find the maximum of $|ze^{−λ/z}| on $D ∩ R$.

My attempts:

a) I computed $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ at $z_0 \in R$ and found that it is equal to $- i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ at $z_0$. Hence $f(z)= e^{-\lambda/z} $ is holomorphic on $R$.

Now to prove continuity of $f$ on $\bar{R}$\ {$0$}, I'm trying to show that $|f(z)| \leq C{(x^2 + y^2)}^{\beta/2}$ for $C \geq 0$ and $\beta > 0$.

So if $z = x + iy \in \bar{R}$\ {$0$}, then Re($z$) $<0$, then I get $|f(z)| = |f(x, y)| = |e^{\frac{-\lambda x}{x^2+y^2}} | ×|e^{\frac{i\lambda y}{x^2+y^2}}|$. But $|e^{\frac{i\lambda y}{x^2+y^2}}| = 1$, so $|f(x, y)| = |e^{\frac{-\lambda x}{x^2+y^2}}| = |e^{\frac{K}{x^2+y^2}}|$, where $K= -\lambda x > 0$ since $x =$ Re($z$) $< 0$. But I don't know how to continue from here. Any help please?

b) lim$_{z→0}$ $e^{−λ/z} = 0$ does not exist since lim$_{z→0^+}$ $e^{−λ/z} = 0$ and lim$_{z→0^-}$ $e^{−λ/z} = \infty$ and $z$lim$_{z→0}$ $e^{−λ/z}$ does not exist.

c) we have that $z \in D ∩ R$, so $z \in D$ => $|z|<1$, and $z \in R$ => Re($z$) $> 0$ => $x>0$. Hence $|ze^{−λ/z}| = |z|×|e^{−λ/z}| < 1 × |e^{−λ/z}| = |e^{\frac{-\lambda x}{x^2+y^2}} | ×|e^{\frac{i\lambda y}{x^2+y^2}}|$. But $|e^{\frac{i\lambda y}{x^2+y^2}}| = 1$, so $|ze^{−λ/z}| < |e^{\frac{-\lambda x}{x^2+y^2}}|$. But now I'm stuck here. How to proceed?

Any help please

Comment: This is *identical* to the question posted here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3651898/42969. Is this pure coincidence or are you the same user?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: By Maximum  Modulus Principle the maximum of $|ze^{-\lambda /z}|$ is attained on the boundary if $D \cap R$ which consists  of two parts: $\{it: -1 \leq t \leq 1\}$ and $\{z: |z|=1, \Re z >0\}$. It is quite easy to find the maximum on these two parts.  Note that $|e^{-\lambda /z}|= |e^{-\lambda \overline {z}|}|=e^{- \lambda \Re z}$ when $|z|=1$.

Comment: Could you please explain further?

Comment: How can I find the maximum? I did not understand

Comment: @Pato Maximum of $|ite^{-\lambda {it}}|$ is $1$ (because $|e^{-\lambda {it}}|=1$. Maximum of $|ze^{-\lambda /z}|=e^{-\lambda \Re z}|$ over the semi-circle is also $1$ because the real part varies from $0$ to $1$ on the semi-circle. Hence the answer is $1$.

Comment: Okay I understand better now. But why do we care about $|ite^{-\lambda it}|$?

Comment: @Pato Part of the boundary of $D \cap R$ is the line $\{it: -1 \leq t \leq 1\}$. Draw  a picture of $R$ and $D$ to see this.